# Error type casts Postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, types, casting

Hello i have this error

Error: psql:/Samsung/VisualCodeStudioWorkspace/1524335164735.pgsql:95: ERROR:  function altaplayer(character varying, integer, integer, character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select altaPlayer( varchar 'Drazen Petrovic',52,80, varchar ...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
psql end.

I cant solve for more than two days... ive tried everyhing...

```
CREATE TYPE player AS (
    nom varchar(20),
    alçada integer,
    pes integer,
    posicio varchar(20),
    equip varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE player_list of player(
    primary key(nom)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
    jugador player
);

INSERT INTO team VALUES(row('Pepelu',190,90,'Base','Barça'));
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Asterix',50,30,'Base','Barça');
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Pepelui',100,90,'Alero','Barça');
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Manolo',10,50,'Base','Barça');
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Juan',50,30,'Base','Barça');
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Fernando Martin',50,30,'Pivot','Barça');
INSERT INTO player_list VALUES('Audie Norris',50,30,'Pivot','Barça');


create or replace function altaPlayer ( varchar(20),int,int,varchar(20),varchar(20)) as $$
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO player_list VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



select altaPlayer('Drazen Petrovic',52,80,'Escolta','Cibona');
```

Answer (score 2):

The function result type must be specified:

```
create or replace function altaplayer ( varchar(20),int,int,varchar(20),varchar(20)) 
returns void -- !!!
as $$
    begin   
        insert into player_list values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
    end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to put the keyword RETURNS.

```
create or replace function altaPlayer
    (varchar(20),int,int,varchar(20),varchar(20)) 
        RETURNS void as $$
```